# Angular Material Is there a way to make backend call an fetch each 100 records from backend but display only 10 in each page in material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular-material-paginator

Angular Material Is there a way to make backend call an fetch each 100 records from backend but display only 10 in each page in material table

**With first page, last page, forward and backward option** that should fetch records from bacend in material paginator and material table

**Backend supports offset and limit option**

Comment: Yes, it is possible with a custom data source. I cannot help but wonder: Why do you need to do such a thing? Why don't fetch 10 records per request from the backend and display them? Whenever the user changes the page, fetch another 10...

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu
Inorder to avoid more number of backend calls it was like that
can you please help me with any demo stackblitz links